# Strange artefacts after applying a subsurface modifier?

Tags: subdivision-surface

After adding a subdivision surface modifier to my model, I get these strange artefacts:

[image]

It looks a little bit like Z fighting, but there is definitely not any intersecting geometry so I am really not sure what is causing it. Does anyone have any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Can you show a bigger screenshot of the mesh in edit mode with all vertexes selected?

Comment: @Sanbaldo I decided to start again to see if I had done something wrong. I have added another screenshot of something similar. A plane with the edge bevelled and a subsurf modifier added.

Answer (score 0):

Same settings as you, and no Z-index fight:

[image]

Can you share the blend file?
thanks